# AJAX loading whole page instead of part of the page to load data from database

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to show image in iframe using AJAX but my full page is loading in every 5 seconds where I want only a content will load if there is any change in the status table.

I think I have do something with the  section. May be I need to transfer the PHP code some where or I need to do some change on DIV. if someone please help me ?

**main.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        function status(){
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET", 
               url: "main.php",
               success: function(data){
                  $('div.divGranite').html(data);
               }
           });
       };
       setTimeout(status, 5000);
    }); 
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="divGranite">

<?php

//Connect to Database
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database");
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $appID = "select * from table where state= '1' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$appID);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $currentID = $row['id']."<br>";
    }


?>
</div>

<div id="display1">

</div>
</body>

<?php

if($currentID != $displayID){
function loadUnload($ID) {

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "usr_web26_1");
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }

        switch ($ID) {
            case $ID == 1:
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo '<iframe src="../imageview/index.php" id="imgiframe" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    break;
                case $ID == 2:      
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo '<iframe src="../videoview/index.php" id="imgiframe" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "Wrong ID";
                break;
            }
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a error <div id="divGranite"> this is an ID you are populating it with a classname $('div.divGranite').html(data); Should be $('div#divGranite').html(data);

Comment: thanks, I have change but getting same problem !

Comment: Is this whole file the same and is it the main.php?

Comment: yes same ! and only this page, have the function. no more page is needed

Comment: It seems to be some errors in the PHP code such as CurrentID never, declared outside the while loop aswell as $displayID never defined either. Alsog loadUnload is never called from the snippet you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This main.php is returning the hole main.php including head-tag and putting it into the divGranite, if you want an ajax request to just return a part of the what main.php produces you need make two files:

1. **main.php** - rendering the default page
2. **ajax.php** - rendering the
       iframe **only**

This would open you up to call ajax.php instead and give you the wanted result
Your **ajax.php** would look something like this,

```
<?php
//Connect to Database
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
if (!$connection) {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
}

$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database");
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
}

$appID = "select * from table where state= '1' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$appID);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $currentID = $row['id']."<br>";
}

if($currentID != $displayID) {
    function loadUnload($ID) {

        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
        if (!$connection) {
            die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
        }

        $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "usr_web26_1");
        if (!$db_select) {
            die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
        }

        switch ($ID) {
            case $ID == 1:
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<iframe src="../imageview/index.php" id="imgiframe" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>';
                echo '</div>';
                break;
            case $ID == 2:      
                echo '<div>';
                echo '<iframe src="../videoview/index.php" id="imgiframe" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>';
                echo '</div>';
                break;
            default:
                echo "Wrong ID";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. main.php is your website, everything is run from here. When the page loads it will load all the HTML outputted by the main.php.
2. After 5 sec main.php will execute the javascript calling an ajax-request to ajax.php the ajax.php will return html to main.php and main.php will then put the response in the correct div.
3. Repeating step 2

Comment: I was separate before and did not read DB. may be I don't have proper idea of writing call for ajax

Comment: Both scripts should have access to your DB, if you are having issues with that there is something else that is wrong

Comment: I have done as you told. create ajax page
<?php

//Connect to Database
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database");
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $appID = "select * from table where state= '1' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$appID);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $currentID = $row['id']."<br>";
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['myValue']=$currentID;
    }
?>

Comment: and in main I am catching the value as:

<script>
    $(function(){
        function status(){
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET", 
               url: "myajax.php",
               success: function(data){
                  $('div#display1').html(data);
               }
           });
       };
       setTimeout(status, 5000);
    });
</script>
</div id="display1">
<?php
session_start();
$ID = $_SESSION['myValue'];

iframe section.....

?>
</div>

Comment: but getting same problem... after 5 seconds I page become blank ! if you please have a look !

Comment: please post both files in a [hastebin](http://hastebin.com/) or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and I can take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61026/discussion-between-tuhin-and-adrian-forsius).

Answer (score 1):

For the ajax code write this

```
$(function(){
    var lastData = '';
        function status(){
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET", 
               url: "main.php",
               success: function(data){
                 if (data != prevData) {
                    $('div.divGranite').html(data);
                    prevData = data;
                }                  
               }
           });
       };
       setTimeout(status, 5000);
    });
```

rest of them is fine !